# What happens to a thread in Python if I overwrite it with a new thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that plays a sound file in loops in separate thread (taken from the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532353/5863503)), and my function get as an argument the name of the file it should play.

```
def loop_play(sound_file):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(sound_file)
    while is_playing:
        play(audio)

def play_sound(sound_file):
    global is_playing
    global sound_thread
    if not is_playing:
        is_playing = True
        sound_thread = Thread(target=loop_play,args=[sound_file])
        sound_thread.daemon = True
        sound_thread.start()
```

Every time I call `play_sound`, I overwrite `sound_thread` and create a new Thread. What happens to the old one? Is it still running in the background? Is there a way to terminate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) When overwriting:

> What happens to the old one? Is it still running in the background?

You have overwritten only reference to the thread, the thread itself is still running.

> Is there a way to terminate it?

There is no clean way of terminating threads, see: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

2) If you want to stop the thread, you shoud use global var that tells the thread to stop.

```
stop = False

def loop_play(sound_file):
    global stop
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(sound_file)
    while is_playing:
        if stop:
            return
        play(audio)

def play_sound(sound_file):
    global is_playing
    global sound_thread
    global stop
    if not is_playing:
        stop = True
        while sound_thread.isAlive():  # Wait for thread to exit
            sleep(1)
        stop = False
        is_playing = True
        sound_thread = Thread(target=loop_play,args=[sound_file])
        sound_thread.daemon = True
        sound_thread.start()
```

Note, that i have not fully understood meaning of is_playing in your code.

Comment: I think that `stop != is_playing` :) So, if I get it right - once the function returns, the thread is dead?